# tidymodels how to set priors for a Naive Bayes model

Tags: r, naivebayes, tidymodels

I want to train a model with a Naive Bayes classifier using the `tidymodels` framework.

Tidymodels uses the `discrim` packages, which itself uses the `klaR` package to estimate Naive Bayes models.

Specifying a NB model in the tidymodels framework can be done with e.g.:

```
naive_Bayes(
  mode = "classification",
  engine = "klaR",
  smoothness = NULL,
  Laplace = NULL)
```

When checking the original NB function in the `klaR` package, though, it has an argument:

> **prior**
> the prior probabilities of class membership. If unspecified,
> the class proportions for the training set are used. If present, the
> probabilities should be specified in the order of the factor levels.

Problem is, I didn't find a way yet to specify these priors in a tidymodel pipeline. Adding the prior parameter just to the `naive_Bayes` function shown above, doesn't work and throws an error:

```
Error in naive_Bayes(prior = rep(0.2, 5)) : 
  unused argument (prior = rep(0.2, 5))
```

Any idea where I can make the parameter settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set this model parameter as an [engine argument](https://www.tmwr.org/models.html#create-a-model):

```r
library(discrim)
#> Loading required package: parsnip

parabolic_prior <- runif(n = 500)

klar_mod <-
    naive_Bayes() %>%
    set_engine("klaR", prior = parabolic_prior) 

translate(klar_mod)
#> Naive Bayes Model Specification (classification)
#> 
#> Engine-Specific Arguments:
#>   prior = parabolic_prior
#> 
#> Computational engine: klaR 
#> 
#> Model fit template:
#> discrim::klar_bayes_wrapper(x = missing_arg(), y = missing_arg(), 
#>     prior = parabolic_prior, usekernel = TRUE)

klar_fit <- fit(klar_mod, class ~ ., data = parabolic)
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Not sure what happened. I tried this yesterday, but it didn't work. Now it does, so all good! Thank you.